# IcCube - How to print a report in landscape?

Tags: google-chrome-headless, iccube, iccube-reporting

Using IcCube reporting V8, I created via the ic3-reporting-api a theme containing a landscape layout.

```
}, {
        layoutConfigId: 'My. A4 (Landscape) Layout',
        pageSize: {
            type: "known",
            name: "A4",
        },
        pageOrientation: "landscape",
        pageMargin: {
            sizeUnits: "cm", ...
```

then created a report based on this layout (which shows correctly as landscape in reporting),
and added on it a print button defined as :

```
action, action@appNotificationType, action@appNotificationPayload
Générer un PDF landscape,print-report,"{""paperSizeName"":""A4"",""pageOrientation"":""landscape"",""fileName"":""Tableau de bord Salle A Landscape (@{DateSelected:asCaption}).pdf""}"
Générer un PDF layoutId,print-report,"{""paperSizeName"":""A4"",""layoutId"":""My. A4 (Landscape) Layout"",""fileName"":""Tableau de bord Salle A Landscape (@{DateSelected:asCaption}).pdf""}"
```

I tried to set as parameters pageOrientation and layoutId because I saw while debugging **pageOrientation** was set to **portrait** and **layoutId** to **undefined**
But my parameters are not considered at all :

```
    01:31:05.276 [General] print options 
Object { inBrowser: false, withState: true, appUrl: "https://localhost:44361/icCube/report/editor", appLocalUrl: "dft", appCustomizationUrl: "-", timeoutS: 300, debugWaitingTimeS: 900, layoutId: undefined, fitToPage: true, fileName: "Tableau de bord Salle A Landscape (2021 nov.).pdf", … }
​appCustomizationUrl: "-"
appLocalUrl: "dft"
appUrl: "https://localhost:44361/icCube/report/editor"
debugWaitingTimeS: 900
fileName: "Tableau de bord Salle A Landscape (2021 nov.).pdf"
fitToPage: true
inBrowser: false
layoutId: undefined
marginBottom: 0
​marginLeft: 0
marginRight: 0
marginTop: 0
pageHeight: 297
pageOrientation: "portrait"
pageSizeName: "A4"
pageSizeUnits: "mm"
pageWidth: 210
​scale: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is currently not available.

A new optional field will be added to the `action@appNotificationPayload` datasource column: `paperOrientation: "portrait"|"landscape"`. By the way the field `layoutId` mentioned in the question is not available and will be ignored. The layout of the report cannot be changed when printing the report.

The [documentation](https://livedemo.iccube.com/icCube/report/viewer?ic3app=shared%3A%2FLive%20Demo%20App&ic3demo=&ic3report=shared%3A%2FLive%20Demo%2FInteractivity%2FApplication%20Notifications) will be updated accordingly when the new version is available with the fix.